# Error in implementing the Mobclix

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, mobclix

I want to integrate the Mobclix in my App. I have included all the frameworks and code required for it . I have also spcified the Mobclix AppID properly. But i am getting errors.

Errors are -

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in libMobclix.a(MobclixCloseWidgetButton.o)

 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libMobclix.a(MobclixRichMediaWebAdView.o)

  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
  -[MobclixCloseWidgetButton startAnimating] in libMobclix.a(MobclixCloseWidgetButton.o)

   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no any idea about it. Please help me out.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your MobclixRichMediaWebAdView.m file is not included in your application target membership.